# iPhone: Press a button -> Centering the map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I hava a Google Maps implementation in my iPhone app. First, the map is set to a default location:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    firstTimeUserLocationCentered = YES;
    [self moveToDefaultLocation];
    firstTimeUserLocationCentered = NO;
    ...
}

- (void)moveToDefaultLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion myDefaultRegion;
    myDefaultRegion.center.latitude = defaultLocLat;
    myDefaultRegion.center.longitude = defaultLocLong;
    myDefaultRegion.span.latitudeDelta = defaultLocLatDelta;
    myDefaultRegion.span.longitudeDelta = defaultLocLongDelta;
    [self.myMapView setRegion:myDefaultRegion animated:YES];
}
```

If the user allows that his location can be used by the app, this method is called:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    if (!firstTimeUserLocationCentered) {
        MKCoordinateRegion myUserRegion;
        myUserRegion.span.latitudeDelta = userLocLatDelta;
        myUserRegion.span.longitudeDelta = userLocLongDelta;
        myUserRegion.center = userLocation.coordinate;
        [self.myMapView setRegion:myUserRegion animated:YES];
        firstTimeUserLocationCentered = YES;
    }
}
```

But now I have the problem, that I want to integrate a button so by pressing it, the location should be centered in the map. So if the user has allowed the application to use the location, the map should be centered where the user is otherwise the default location should be used, so I can call `[self moveToDefaultLocation]`.
How can I do this?

Also I am searching for an icon for this "user location centering" button. In this image, there is a button icon which I am looking for: http://gadgetress.freedomblogging.com/files/2008/01/iphonemapslg.jpg The icon on the left hand side of "Search", where can I get it?

Best Regards Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with:

```
MKUserLocation *myUserLocation = self.myMapView.userLocation;
if (!myUserLocation.location) {
    [self moveToDefaultLocation];
} else {
   self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.myUserLocation.location.coordinate;
}
```

But I did not found this icon... Does anyone know where I can get this icon?

Comment: Use `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` to get the animation (and make it similar to your default location method).

Answer (score 0):

[Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) has a couple of maps icons, one is like the one you linked to.